# What governs the type of the expression?

Tags: c++, cout

I'm reading through Stroustrup's *Principles and Practice using C++* book and while completing an exercise, I noticed `cout` exhibit some interesting behavior which I don't fully understand.

On line 7 in the code below, I expected that `char + char = char`, however in this case `char + char = int`, therefore outputting `"113"`. I understand that the character `'0'` (48) + `'A'` (65) equals `'q'` (113) when represented as an `int`, but what is governing this expression resulting in an `int` instead of a `char`?

As the variable `my_char` contains the same value, I expected **both** `cout` statements to output `"q"`.

```cpp
1  #include <iostream>
2  using namespace std;
3
4  int main() {
5     char my_char = '0' + 'A';   // 'q'
6     cout << my_char   << endl;  // output: "q"
7     cout << '0' + 'A' << endl;  // output: "113" -> why not "q"?
8
9     return 0;
10 }
```

Comment: Marked as a duplicate - in the duplicate question, you can find the type conversion rules for operations between primitive integral types. tl;dr: the smallest type for arithmetic operations is int, so both char operands will be converted to int before performing the + operation.